# Where can I find high-level Corki VOD's?

Tags: league-of-legends

I'd like to watch some standard high-level Corki gameplay, as he's my preferred character. I've never seen him used, though, in the dozen or so professional games that I've watched.

Could someone link to a specific VOD of a tournament game where Corki is chosen?

Preferably the Corki plays an important role in a close game, so that his skill and item build is highlighted, but isn't so dominant that the game isn't a completely unrealistic expectation when I try to emulate his play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in to some of "imaqtpie"s videos. He played Corki quite a few times at IEM Hanover.

http://leaguecraft.com/news/intel-extreme-masters-hannover-match-replays-132.xhtml

Check the Dignitas matches.